# How can I access the SQLITE databases created by Chrome?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome

Chrome can create sqlite databases using window.openDatabase. How do I access the sqlite database using a standalone application like an sqlite manager?

When I update the Sqlite database using a standalone application, will chrome automatically update its database to or would that still require a restart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a windows platform, you can try this [sqlitebrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). It works ok (for example with the sqlite-files you can find in your chrome user profile).